# c# progress bar percentage

Tags: c#, progress-bar, percentage

I have a progress bar in a winform c# application and I sue that as a progress indicator.
The progress bar can have a different Maximum size depending on the amount of user input (which can go over 100) so this is how I set it up:

```
this.pbLoadingWrite.Maximum = Input.Length;
this.pbLoadingWrite.Step = 1;
```

then just update the progress bar with:

```
this.pbLoadingWrite.PerformStep();
```

All works fine but I would like to display a % number on top of the progress bar for better visibility.

Since the Input.Length can be > 100, what's the syntax for displaying the percentage? Are there any helper functions built into VS c#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculating the percentage is quite easy in this case

```
int percent = (progressbar1.Value / progressbar.Maximum) * 100;
```

Break down:

```
value = 56, Max = 300,

56 / 300 = 0.186666
0.186666 * 100 = 18.666%
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was missing the 100 actually duh I think you need float or double becuase percent is always 0 when you do something like (4 / 5) *100

Comment: @sd_dracula, you can use an integer if you multiply first: (100 * 4) / 5 = 80

Comment: I have forgotten how it works in C# but in most languages when you divide by integers you get bad surprise as a result - an integer. If I'm wrong, please do correct my statement for C#.